# How to detect if a folder is a github repository

Tags: git, bash, github

I would like to code a bash script in order to create a github repository if the current folder doesn't have one.

Do you know how I can tell if the current folder already has a directory or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git remote -v` to see if the result contains "github.com"

Comment: Further to this is, if a directory has a `.git` directory, you can tell it is the root level of a git repo, running `git remote` -v as Akagi suggested will show you if that directory is versioned by git.